# How can I limit the number of mails sent from a specific email account in cpanel or WHM

Tags: email, spam-prevention, cpanel, exim, whm

I have a spam issue with an email account. Undelivered emails are being returned to the mail box. These emails were not sent from the box. Its seems someone or something is bouncing the emails off this account. Since it is an important organisation account., I cant shut it down. So while I try to fix it, I will like to configure this account to only receive emails and not be able to send emails out.

How can I achieve this through either CPanel or WHM or Exim?

Will be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like [backscatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(email)) from a forged email address.

Comment: Ok. I have read up the backscatter article and its interesting. I have made a few tweaks to my Exim though and I am watching the response. Bu it would be nice to have a direct tool to just prevent sending of mail for a specific email account because only this account seems to have this problem so far. It is an advertised email account for receiviing correspondence from customers